# What can we say about the eigendecomposition of quantum channels?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, quantum-information, linear-algebra

It is known that quantum channels, being CPTP maps, map density operators to density operators. And thus, they can be seen as superoperators. Similar to operators, where eigenstates and eigenvalues can be derived, one can also define the eigen-operators (typically, being a mixed state) and eigenvalues of quantum channels $\mathbb{N}$:
$$\mathbb{N}(\Phi_j)=\lambda_j \Phi_j.$$

See page 3 of this [lecture note](https://indico.ictp.it/event/9023/material/slides/5.pdf) for the deduction. Given these similarities between operators (e.g., Hermitian operators) and quantum channels, the question is what can we say about the properties of their eigendecomposition? Specifically, is the basis of the superoperator $\{\Phi_j\}$ a complete basis? Namely, does $\sum_j\Phi_j=I$ hold? Besides, do the elements in the basis orthogonal to each other? Here, the orthogonality may not be directly followed from the state vector, but maybe something like Hilber-Schmidt orthogonal, i.e., $\mathrm{tr}(\Phi_i\Phi_j)=\delta_{ij}$.

PS: I would be really grateful if someone could point me to some literature regarding this topic.

Comment: You might want to read "Quantum computation and quantum information" by Nielsenand Chuang, Chapters 2 and 8.

Comment: cross-posted on https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/37379/55

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, no. Here is a quantum channel which provides a counter example. Let $|i\rangle$, $i = 1, \dots, n$ be an orthonormal basis on an $n$ dimensional Hilbert space, and define
$$A_i = |1\rangle\langle i|.$$
The $A_i$ form a set of Kraus operators, and we may define the quantum channel,
$$\mathcal{N}(\cdot) = \sum_{i=1}^n A_i (\cdot)A_i^\dagger.$$
Let $\rho = \sum_{ij}\rho_{ij}|i\rangle \langle j|$ be an arbitrary density matrix. Then
$$\mathcal{N}(\rho) = \sum_{i=1}^n \rho_{ii}|1\rangle \langle 1| = |1\rangle \langle 1|$$
So, the only density operator which is an eigenoperator of $\mathcal{N}$ is the pure state $|1\rangle \langle 1|$, with eigenvalue $1$.

**Edit:**

More generally, we can ask under what circumstances we might be guaranteed the existence of an orthonormal basis of eigenoperators. In this context, we will be thinking of the channel $\mathcal{N}$ as a linear operator on the Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^n\times \mathbb{C}^n$ equipped with the Hilbert-Schmidt inner product. (Actually, a channel is technically only defined on the so-called positive cone, but in finite dimensions we may always extend the action of a channel to the entire set of $n\times n$ complex matrices). Recall the definition of the *channel adjoint*, which is the superoperator $\mathcal{N}^\dagger$ which satisfies
$$\text{tr}(A\mathcal{N}(B)) = \text{tr}(\mathcal{N^\dagger}(A)B)$$
for all $A, B\in \mathbb{C}^n\times \mathbb{C}^n$. Comparing with the Hilbert Schmidt inner product,
$$\langle A, B\rangle_{HS} = \text{tr}(A^\dagger B),$$ we can see that the channel adjoint and the Hilbert-Schmidt adjoint coincide up to conjugation of the argument:
$$\mathcal{N}^{\dagger_{HS}} = * \circ \mathcal{N}^\dagger \circ *$$
where the operator $*$ takes a given matrix to its Hermitian conjugate. We can simplify this further by noting that $\mathcal{N}^\dagger$ in fact commutes with the $*$ operation, and so the HS-adjoint coincides with the usual notion of channel adjoint. One can check this by explicit calculation:
$$\mathcal{N}^{\dagger_{HS}}(B)= (*\circ \mathcal{N}^\dagger \circ *)(B) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n A_i^\dagger B^\dagger A_i\right)^\dagger = \sum_{i=1}^n A_i^\dagger B A_i = \mathcal{N}^\dagger(B)$$

Now recall that an operator on a Hilbert space is guaranteed a complete orthonormal basis if it is normal (thanks to @Norbert Schuch for pointing this out), i.e. if $\mathcal{N}^\dagger \mathcal{N} = \mathcal{N}\mathcal{N}^\dagger$. Examples of channels with this property are self adjoint channels ($\mathcal{N} = \mathcal{N}^\dagger$) and unitary channels ($\mathcal{N}^\dagger = \mathcal{N}^{-1}$).

Comment: Couldn't I also say that there **is** an operator basis corresponding to $\Gamma_{m,n} = | m \rangle \hspace{-0.4mm} \langle n |$, where $\Gamma_{1,1}$ has eigenvalue 1 and all others have eigenvalue 0? It's just that this choice of basis is **not** unique, except for $\Gamma_{1,1}$.

Comment: $\Gamma_{m, n}$ has eigenvalue $0$ if $m\neq n$, but if $m = n$, then $\mathcal{N}(\Gamma_{n,n}) = |1\rangle \langle 1|$, and by linearity there are no eigenoperators which span the diagonal basis elements.

Comment: Indeed, the set of eigenoperators of $\mathcal{N}$ on $\mathbb{C}^n\times \mathbb{C}^n$ is $\{\Gamma_{1, 1}\}\cup \{\Gamma_{m, n} | m\neq n\}$ which is not complete.

Comment: I had missed that part of your answer, and I agree with what you've written here! I guess this channel isn't even "diagonalizable" since it maps $N$ of the $N^2$ operators $\Gamma_{m,n}$ to the *same* operator $\Gamma_{1,1}$.

Comment: Perhaps it's worth pointing out that Hermitian operators' eigenstates always form a complete set, but a generic operator need not have a complete set of eigenstates. And channels need not be Hermitian acting on the space of operators, so they need not have a complete set of states, as in the example above.

Comment: Good point, just added an edit to the answer.

Comment: @pseudo-goldstone Being normal is necessary and sufficient for being unitary diagonalizable (i.e., complete set of orthogonal eigenvectors).

Comment: ... as pointed out in a comment on qc.se, a good example of a channel which is normal but not hermitian is unitary time evolution.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch ah yes, thanks for the comment. Just updated the answer.

Answer (score 4):

As you observe correctly, $\mathbb N$ is a linear map. Thus, the same holds as for any eigendecomposition of linear maps.

In particular, there need not be a complete basis of eigenvectors (there can be Jordan blocks), and eigenvectors are not orthogonal.

To get a complete eigenbasis, you need a diagonalizable map $\mathbb N$, and for orthogonality, it needs to be normal -- just as for any linear map.

If you want a good source on quantum channels, what I can recommend are Michael Wolf's lecture notes [Quantum Channels and Operations: Guided Tour](https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/node?id=1701036&change_language=en).

Comment: Besides, it is known that diagonalizable matrices are dense in the space of all matrices. Does this mean that we can make every complete-positive (trace non-increasing) map to be diagonalizable by adding a small perturbation to it?

Comment: @ironmanaudi The diagonalizable channels are indeed dense in the set of all channels, as I show in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.19643). In fact, every convex set has this approximation property as long as there exists one element the eigenvalues of which are all distinct, cf. [this paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2160975). (updated my previous comment to include references)

Comment: @FrederikvomEnde Much obliged!